# In Solr, can I apply a boost to each term in a phrase?

Tags: solr

Using Solr, if I have a phrase:

"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Can I apply my own weighting to these words at index-time?

Something like this:

"The^1 quick^2 brown^2 fox^3 ..." etc

And, then, I'd like to have those numbers influence the score.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna check payloads: [Lucid](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) or ultramagnus. You can add weights to terms at index time this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boost query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents). So if you are searching on title field, you can query saying `bq=(title:The)^1&bq=(title:quick)^2&bq=(title:brown)^2`  and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so the way you have written it:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting a Term

*Boosting a Term
Lucene provides the relevance level of matching documents based on the terms found. To boost a term use the caret, "^", symbol with a boost factor (a number) at the end of the term you are searching. The higher the boost factor, the more relevant the term will be.*

Boosting allows you to control the relevance of a document by boosting its term. For example, if you are searching for

jakarta apache
and you want the term "jakarta" to be more relevant boost it using the ^ symbol along with the boost factor next to the term. You would type:

jakarta^4 apache
This will make documents with the term jakarta appear more relevant. You can also boost Phrase Terms as in the example:

"jakarta apache"^4 "Apache Lucene"
By default, the boost factor is 1. Although the boost factor must be positive, it can be less than 1 (e.g. 0.2)

Comment: I believe he is talking about boosting the score of terms when they are indexed, not when they are in a query.